# running roundcube through cpanel in an iframe

Tags: iframe, cpanel, roundcube

I'm setting up a web app where I need roundcube to run inside an iframe. In my case, roundcube is loaded by cpanel. If I load the default cpanel webmail url in the iframe "mydomain.com:2096", after log in, cpanel webmail page breaks out of the iframe and become full page where it asks me to load roundcube.

My question is how can I keep this page and the roundcube page inside the iframe after log in?

I tried to load roundcube direct url in the iframe: "mydomain.com:2096/3rdpary/roundcube". It still lets me log in with the cpanel login form, but it stops at redirecting because of js same origin error.

So my understanding at this stage is that I will need to find a way to contain cpanel itself inside the iframe. Any suggestions?